# C++ Linear search algorithm, determining the number of elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, linear-search

This code is from the Geeks for Geeks Algorithms section and i do not understand this part

```
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

In the main function, specifially why the division with sizeof(arr[0]) which would lead to half the number of actual elements in the array.
Hope someone can explain me this.

```
// C++ code to linearly search x in arr[]. If x 

// is present then return its location, otherwise 
// return -1 

#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int search(int arr[], int n, int x) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        if (arr[i] == x) 
            return i; 
    return -1; 
} 

int main(void) 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 }; 
    int x = 10; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
    int result = search(arr, n, x); 
(result == -1)? cout<<"Element is not present in array"
                : cout<<"Element is present at index " <<result; 
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's consider the declared array

```
int arr[] = { 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 };
```

As the size of the array is not specified then the number of elements in the array is equal to the number of initializers.

It is not difficult to count the number of elements. It is equal to `5`. So the array consists from 5 elements of the type `int`.

The memory allocated to the array is equal to `5 * sizeof( int )`. it is the same as `5 * sizeof( arr[0] )` because the element `arr[0]` has the type `int`.

so you have that the size of the whole arrau is

```
sizeof( arr ) = 5 * sizeof( arr[0] )
```

Having this formula it is easy to determine the number of elements in the array having its size and the size of stored elements. That is

```
5 = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] )
```

So having an arbitrary array `arr` you can determine the number of elements the following way

```
N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] )
```

The function search expects that the second argument will specify the number of elements in the passed array

```
int search(int arr[], int n, int x);
```

And it is calculated as shown above that is

```
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
int result = search(arr, n, x);
```

If you compiler supports the C++ 17 Standard then instead of using this formula you could use the standard function `std::size` like

```
int result = search(arr, std::size( arr ), x);
```

Pay attention to that the function declaration and definition is bad.

For example the expression `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` has the type `size_t` but the corresponding function parameter has the type `int`. The type `int` can be not enough large to store values of the type `size_t`. Secondly as the array is not being changed in the function then the first parameter shall have the qualifier `const`.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t search( const int arr[], size_t n, int x) 
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i != n && arr[i] != x ) ++i;

    return i;
}
```

If the target value is not found in the array then the function returns the size of the array that is n.

Pay attention that there is standard algorithm `std::find` that can be used instead of the function.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof()` returns the memory used by the element.

Lets assume `c++` uses x bytes for `int`.

So `int` array with 5 element will be of size 5x.

`sizeof(arr)` returns the memory used by integer array with 5 elements which is 5x.

`sizeof(arr[0])` returns the memory used by integer which is x.

So `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` will return 5 as the size

Comment: Allthough `int` would be allowed to be only 2 bytes wide, on most modern systems it's 4 bytes. Good answer otherwise.

Comment: The answer is correct, but you could avoid using any particular size for `int`, and get the same result.

Comment: Thank you, got it!

Comment: @cigien Thanks for the suggestion. Updated my answer.

Comment: @churill Updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The statement `int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);`  is used to find the number of elements in `arr`.

### How It Works ?

- `sizeof(arr)` - This will return the amount of memory used by `arr` in bytes. In our case, `arr` is an array and so the expression will return the size occupied by `arr` in bytes.
- `sizeof(arr[0])` - This will also return the amount of memory stored by `arr[0]`(**Note** : its not `arr`) . In our case, `arr[0]` is an element of array and so the expression will return the size occupied by `arr[0]` in bytes.
- Now, the `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]` will return the number of elements in the array. How? - The `sizeof(arr)` gave us total size of array in bytes and `sizeof(arr[0])` gave us the size of just 1 element. So dividing them, we get the number of elements in our array.

---

**NOTE :** the size of each element will be same, so it is not that you only have to choose `arr[0]`. You could have chosen `arr[3]` or any other index given it was within array bounds

Hope this clears your doubt !